# JavaScript Content Tabs

Tags: javascript, css

I'm not that great at JavaScript and could use some help. I want to get my code to be content all on one page, but my JavaScript code change the content of my DIVs on a button click. I have this done and working.

However, I want the first DIV to be the default open one when the page first opens. And when a particular div is open, I want the corresponding button to change background colors (via CSS). This is the part that I am stuck on. Help?

My code so far:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="why-container">


    <div class="icon-nav">

        <a class="link" href="#tab" data-link="first"><img src="img1.png" class="blue-icons"></a>
        <a class="link" href="#tab" data-link="second"><img src="img2.png" class="blue-icons"></a>
        <a class="link" href="#tab" data-link="third"><img src="img3.png" class="blue-icons"></a>
        <a class="link" href="#tab" data-link="fourth"><img src="img4.png" class="blue-icons"></a>

    </div>

    <div class="why-content">

        <div class="textWord_tab" data-link="first">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="content-box-header">Content Tab 1</div>
                <p class="content-box-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="textWord_tab" data-link="second">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="content-box-header">Content Tab 2</div>
                <p class="content-box-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>         
        </div>


        <div class="textWord_tab" data-link="third">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="content-box-header">Content Tab 3</div>
                <p class="content-box-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>         
        </div>


        <div class="textWord_tab" data-link="fourth">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="content-box-header">Content Tab 4</div>
                <p class="content-box-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>         
        </div>


    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.textWord_tab').hide();

    $('.link').click(function () {
        $('.textWord_tab').hide();
        $('.textWord_tab[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only work with hashtags and href, define your buttons like this

```
<div class="icon-nav">

    <a class="link" href="#first"><img src="img1.png" class="blue-icons"></a>
    <a class="link" href="#second"><img src="img2.png" class="blue-icons"></a>
    <a class="link" href="#third"><img src="img3.png" class="blue-icons"></a>
    <a class="link" href="#fourth"><img src="img4.png" class="blue-icons"></a>

</div>
```

and you js like this (the class "selected" have to be defined to design the selected buttons):

```
//select all tabs and hide
var tabs = $('.textWord_tab').hide();
var buttons = $('.link');

function showTab(key) {
    //select showing tab
    var tabToShow = tabs.filter('[data-link=' + key + ']');

    //check if tab is hidden
    if(tabToShow.is(':hidden')) {
        buttons.removeClass('selected')
            .filter('[href=#' + key + ']').addClass('selected');
        tabs.hide();
        tabToShow.stop().fadeIn({
            width: '200px'
        }, 300);
        return true;
    }

}
//show the first tab
if(!window.location.hash || !showTab(window.location.hash)) {
    showTab(buttons.filter(':first').attr('href').substr(1));
}

buttons.click(function () {
    showTab($(this).attr('href').substr(1));
});
```

you can see, the hashtag will be updated with the data-link value. on a reload the last opened tab will be open instead the first

Comment: Fantastic! That added the functionality that I wanted. Would you perchance know how I can do the tab effects with the background change for the buttons?

Comment: @ticklishoctopus watch my edit, just a smoother solution (adding also the "selected" class)

Comment: Yes! That did the trick! Thanks so much for your help. Your commented notes were really helpful as well.